# jQuery Select change JSON/Array Values

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to dissect JSON data to do the following:

1. Select Option > List each Type
   e.g Activity/Adventure, Beach Escape, City Break.
2. On Select Change > List each Types Value along with the Country allocated to this Option.
   e.g 1 USA, 2 Australia, 3 Japan

[image: Design Example]

**Current Problems:**

1. Select Option > I'm unable to gather each Type without making a loop which then brings all types for all Countries.
2. On Select Change > Because the above doesn't work it was difficult to develop this section but it still doesn’t work to plan. It now lists each Country without the Type Value and displays JSON instead of just the values.

[image: Current Issue]

I have uploaded the project to GitHub: https://github.com/adamkwadsworth/Audley-Travel
JSON - https://github.com/adamkwadsworth/Audley-Travel/blob/master/json/locations.json
**Problematic Code:**

```
function filterData(){
  var rawdata = jsonData;
  //console.log(rawdata);
  var data = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < rawdata.length; index++) {
    var item = rawdata[index];
    var item1 = {};
    var type1 = {}, type2 = {}, type3 = {}, type4 = {}, type5 = {}, type6 = {}, type7 = {}, type8 = {}, type9 = {}, type10 = {};
    item1.Country = item.Location;
    type1["Activity/Adventure"] = item["Activity/ Adventure"];
    type2["Beach Escape"] = item["Beach Escape"];
    type3["City Break"] = item["City Break"];
    type4["Food/Culture"] = item["Food/Culture"];
    type5["Visiting Friends/Family"] = item["Visiting Friends/Family"];
    type6["Great Train/Boat Journey"] = item["Great Train/Boat Journey"];
    type7.Scenery = item.Scenery;
    type8.Sightseeing = item.Sightseeing;
    type9["Theme Park"] = item["Theme Park"];
    type10["Wildlife/Safari"] = item["Wildlife/Safari"];
    var types = [type1, type2, type3, type4, type5, type6, type7, type8, type9, type10];
    var items = [item1, types];
    data.push(items);
    var filterdata1 = JSON.stringify(item1);
    $('.filterlist').append('<li><span>1</span>'+filterdata1+'</li>');
  }
  console.log(data);
```

**Console Log:**
[image]

Comment: Question posting tip: posts sometimes get closed or edited here if links are included to repositories or zip files. I _think_ it's OK in this instance since you've offered a good deal of other detail, but be aware that we're ideally looking for questions to be as self-contained as possible (broken links are a bit of a problem, and community members are trying to deal with that). If you want to demonstrate a live problem, consider a JS Fiddle or similar (as well as putting all the relevant code in the post, of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While you've specifically tagged this question with jQuery, I'll offer an alternative approach: using an MVVM library instead.
By restructuring your data storage a little, this can turn into very straightforward code with, for example, [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/):

```js
var items = {
  'Activity/Adventure': ['USA', 'Canada', 'Russia'],
  'Beach Escape': ['Mexico', 'Egypt'],
  'Food': ['Italy', 'France']
};

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    selected: Object.keys(items)[0],
    items: items
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-repeat="items">{{$key}}</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li v-repeat="item: items[this.selected]">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```